# How to get the ascent and descent of a specific string with font applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, fontmetrics

Saved Custom Font data to `UIFont`.

```
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceHanSans-Medium" size:nEmSize];
```

Now I want to get the height of a string.

However, the value of `nEmSize`, which is the size of the font, is returned for the height of the string.

```
NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
const CGSize textSize = [strText sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];

return (NSInteger)(floor(textSize.height));
```

So I thought of doing a `descent - ascent` on the `FontMetrics` data.
But I did a search and looked up the documentation, but couldn't find a way to get a value from `UIFont`.

Is there a way to get the `descent` value and `ascent` value of a specific string with font applied?